# Need Resource suggestions about Indicators and Signs in Governmental Open data

Tags: data-request, government, uses-of-open-data, releasing-data

I am studying for my master’s degree in the Interaction Design domain. For my upcoming Capstone project, can someone please direct me to good resources that talk about *governmental open data at the community level* :

- Why do cities in the US and around the world use open data. What was
  the need in the first place? (long-term view)
- What are the pros and cons of using Indicators/ Signs. (History and
  current usage). A good or a bad example.
- Any academic study that is done from the user's perspective. Who uses open data. What decisions do they make? Challenges users face. (This is huge for me - users, audience. My goal is to understand the open data users - make it a little easy for them and ultimately help the end users.)

Pl let me know if I need to refine my questions or if these are good to start.

Comment: What are indicators/signs?

Comment: By Indicators I mean something like this : http://www.bostonindicators.org/indicators

Comment: It seem like you are looking for studies on community indicators? I would recommend just asking one question at a time.

Comment: Personally, I think that signs are a good thing, up to a point ... my town's now getting overrun with signs (bail bondsman across the street from me putting up an A-frame sign on my property, so many traffic signs that people just start tuning them out and will make a U-turn directly in front of the 'No U Turn' sign, etc.).  I'd love to see something like http://www.spiegel.de/international/spiegel/controlled-chaos-european-cities-do-away-with-traffic-signs-a-448747.html